# Chat Bubble for WhatsApp Messenger

Tags: nexus-5, whatsapp-messenger

I was wondering if it is at all possible to get chat bubbles(similar to the ones used on facebook messenger) for whatsapp messenger on my nexus 5. Is there an app I can download, or a process that will allow me to get chat bubbles like this for whatsapp?

These are the chat bubbles I'm talking about (the little heads)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install the app [Whatsapp Chat heads](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dregens.whatsappbubblenotifications&hl=en) I am not sure if it runs on Nexus 5, or that it shows Chat-heads or just the name of the chat.

Comment: Who is the designer of the app? Dregens Teknoloji?

Answer (score 0):

Try this app: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stallware.dashdow.whatsapp.lite

and see this article:
http://trendblog.net/how-to-get-chat-heads-whatsapp-android/

Answer (score 0):

Dunka, you can install my app, [WhatsBubbles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rodrigopontes.whatsbubbles), which provides a nearly identical user experience and allows users to preview, open and respond to conversations.

Give it a try!

Comment: Please confirm what relationship (if any) you have with this app: it's OK to recommend your own app on this site, provided you're honest about it.

Comment: Yes, I am the app's developer. I did not mean to be deceptive, I am just trying to promote my app. I will update my comment.